# Drupal form creating method without using a module

Tags: forms

I am working on a Drupal site and it has a custom form in the frontend. I want to remove that form, but the problem is it is not generated by a custom module.

There is only one custom module. so I disabled it to check if that's the module generating the form. I cleared the cache also.

But the form is still there. So is there any other method of adding a form to a Drupal site without using a custom module?

Comment: The form might be declared at the theme level - grep the files for the installed theme for the phrase `drupal_get_form` to find out

Comment: It could be a block with drupal_render(drupal_get_form()) and PHP enabled or a webform (in a block).

Comment: May be some bad coders hardcoded it in your template files. Try that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments and the other answer says, there are several possibilities:

- A contributed module such as [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform).
- Someone with very bad habits hard-coded that form inside templates, other modules or even Drupal core.
- A block/node could contain that form, specially if the PHP-filter is enabled. Even with the HTML filter enabled (and submitting the form to another page).

If you see some custom text, or the name of the fields are unique or rare, you could try to search inside Drupal root directory for them:

```
grep -r 'Custom text' /var/www/drupal
```

[phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) includes a functionality to search across an entire database. If you feel desperate, try to search inside the Drupal database for the text you see in the form.

Examining the outputted HTML code could help. You will see if the form has an ID, for example.

Comment: thnax for the answer...

Answer (score 1):

Check if the webform module is installed.

Chances are that the form is in a block. You might want to check your block list if it is there.